# TRS female jack symbol in Kicad

Tags: kicad, trs

There is a device which is powered and also outputs signal by its TRS connector as shown below:

[image]

This TRS connector needs a female correspondent for my circuit. 
I made a small board and need to add my schematics the female jack of this TRS.

In KiCad there is the following symbol:

[image]

But Im not sure if it is a TRS female jack, since 2 and 1 are seems connected.

Is this how it supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is "jack_2P", which at first glance seems to be for TRS (Tip-ring-sleeve), except it only shows 2 pins from the cable and 1 extra. The extra pin in the jack is like a switch that disconnects from pin one when the plug is inserted (it bends). Thus it almost looks like your jack is for a 2-pin cable.

Below is an example of what you want; a jack for TRS (a 3-pin cable):

[image: TRS jack pinout]

Again you have an extra pin, of which is just there as a switch. But now you have the ring (aka shield/ground), and the other two conductors.

The thing is, my diagram looks pretty much your like your diagram, except the ground has it's own pin.

**It's possible that your "jack_2p" is the same thing, and that the ground is just not shown as a pin. You may still be able to connect to it.**

Answer (score 1):

> But Im not sure if it is a TRS female jack, since 2 and 1 are seems
>   connected

It's not the jack socket that you want. The jack socket you show is suitable for a standard mono jack plug. Notice the difference between the two plugs: -

[image]

The socket symbol you have is one that has a contact operated when you insert the plug. What you probably need is a three pin symbol like this: -

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I dont know what could be alternative. There is no female TRS for 3 pins in KiCad.

Comment: Im also confused what pin 2 is in real world if it is for mono.

Comment: Just redraw it in KiCAD - I'm sure it has the facilities. The mono jack is the lower plug in my picture.

Answer (score 0):

Pin 2 is an extra switch to disconnect something, for example the speaker when an earphone is plugged in. In Hi-Z audio inputs the switch shorts the input to reduce the hum and buzz that a Hi-Z input easily collects when nothing is plugged in.

Your symbol is for mono plug, there's no wire for GND. Find a female stereo TRS jack.

Beware: Hot +24V is extremely easily shorted, if your male connector is the output.

Comment: Why would it be easily shorted? Im kind of worried now. Yes male is the output of the device and female will be in my circuit.

Comment: @user16307 it's very easy to position something metallic between  the +24V and the GND - anything!- coins, tools, some metallic box... A tenth of a second is enough to smoke if your +24V supply is not protected against a high current shorting. Normally hot outputs are well hidden out of uninteded touching.

Comment: Yes tip will be 24VDC. Is there a risk during the insertion of plug to the jack?